# conemu - how to 'group input' in a task?

Tags: conemu

I have created a task in conemu which launches 3 consoles and ssh to 3 different servers. I would like to also 'group inputs' directly when launching this new task.

Right now, I need to press Apps+G once the 3 consoles are up in order to be able to run the same command in all three consoles.

Is there a way to get Apps+G to be called when launching the task without I having to do it ?

Comment: Create fourth console with [GuiMacro](http://conemu.github.io/en/GuiMacro.html) command

Comment: Hi Maximus, could you elaborate a bit more ? A simplistic example/sample would be just great :) Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Supposing you start three `cmd.exe` consoles. First one would be active. Last line executes [GuiMacro](http://conemu.github.io/en/GuiMacro.html) and immediately terminates.

```
>cmd.exe /k "%ConEmuBaseDir%\CmdInit.cmd"
cmd.exe /k "%ConEmuBaseDir%\CmdInit.cmd"
cmd.exe /k "%ConEmuBaseDir%\CmdInit.cmd"
cmd /c -cur_console:n ConEmuC -GuiMacro GroupInput 4
```